# Is this related to calculus? $1^3,2^3,3^3,4^3,5^3,6^3,\ldots$ $\to$ $7,19,37,61,91,\ldots$ $\to$ $12,18,24,30,\ldots$ $\to$ $6,6,6,\ldots$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

To better illustrate what I mean, I will list 3 examples:

**Example 1):**

In calculus if $y = x^3$, then the derivatives are:

$y' = 3x^2$

$y'' = 6x$

$y''' = 6$

Other demonstration When $x^3$:

$1^3,2^3,3^3,4^3,5^3,6^3,7^3,8^3,9^3,10^3...$

$1,8,27,64,125,216,343,512,729,1000...$

This list is growing by:

$7+19+37+61+91+127+169+217+271... $

This list is growing by:

$12+18+24+30+36+42+48+54...$

This list is growing by

$6+6+6+6+6+6+6+6...$

It took me $3$ steps to get to the constant $6$

**Example 2):**

In calculus if $y = x^4$, then the derivatives are:

$y' = 4x^3$

$y'' = 12x^2$

$y''' = 24x$

$y'''' = 24$

Other demonstration When $x^4$:

$1^4,2^4,3^4,4^4,5^4,6^4,7^4,8^4,9^4,10^4...$

$1,16,81,256,625,1296,2401,4096,6561,10000...$

$15+65+175+369+671+1105+1695+2465+3439... $

$50+110+194+302+43+590+770+974..$

$60+84+108+132+156+180+204...$

$24+24+24+24+24+24+24...$

It took me $4$ steps to get to the constant $24$

**Example 3):**

In calculus if $y = x^5$, then the derivatives are:

$y' = 5x^4$

$y'' = 20x^3$

$y''' = 60x^2$

$y'''' = 120x$

$y''''' = 120$

Other demonstration  When $x^5$:

$1^5,2^5,3^5,4^5,5^5,6^5,7^5,8^5,9^5,10^5...$

$1,32,243,1024,3125,7776,16807,32768,59049,100000...$

$31+211+781+2101+4651+9031+15961+26281+40951... $

$180 + 570 + 1320 + 2550 + 4380 + 6930 + 10320 + 14670...$

$390 + 750 + 1230+1830+2550+3390 +4350...$

$360+480+600+720+840+960...$

$120+120+120+120+120..$

It took me $5$ steps to get to the constant $120$

I am a bit confused  because  with calculus the idea is to get the rate of change for a specific point, and in the other demonstration we are obtaining the rate of change between $2$ consecutive points. Also the amount of steps are the same and the final results are the same.

I am trying to understand why am I getting the same final results in the same amount of steps?

Comment: **In example 1), the first step in calculus is $y=3x^2$ and in the other demonstration, the first step results in $7+19+37+61+91+127+169+217+271+\cdots $ and none of these numbers can be represented as $3x^2$.** These are not the numbers of form $y=3x^2$, these are the first differences between the numbers of the form $y=3x^2$

Comment: @Devansh Kamra Yes i understand this, but I was trying to illustrate that the amount of steps are the same, but the results in between the steps until we get to the final result are different.

Comment: Try googling "Calculus of finite differences."

Comment: @Devansh Kamra just wanted to mention that per your comment I have removed that part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the results are related to calculus. Since all examples are similar, let's just focus on example 1. Actually, what you get is

$\int_1^23x^2dx=7$; $\int_1^33x^2dx=7+19$; $\int_1^43x^2dx=7+19+37$...

$\int_1^2(\int_x^{x+1}6tdt)dx=12$; $\int_1^3(\int_x^{x+1}6tdt)dx=30$...

$\int_1^2(\int_x^{x+1}(\int_t^{t+1}6du)dt)dx=6$;$\int_1^3(\int_x^{x+1}(\int_t^{t+1}6du)dt)dx=6+6$...

Every time we calculate the difference of the sequence, we are somehow derivating the sequence. So the amount of steps to get the constant sequence is the same with that to get the constant function $y=6$. Maybe the relationship is more clear from the integral prespective. You can just focus on the multiplicities of integrals, and the integrant, while ignoring the other details.

In general, the results from derivatives of a function and the differences of a sequence is not equal. Your $6$ is a special case, because the function $y=6$ is a constant function. This is due to the difference of derivation in continuous case and discrete case.

The following description might not be rigorous. In the continuous case, we "link" those points $(n,n^3)$ with a smooth curve $y=x^3$; but in the discrete case, what you are doing is somehow to "link" these points by segments. So the result is different. But given that the "curve" and the "segments" can be somehow similar, you can find some interesting relationship between them, for example, your 6 in example 1.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why the amount of steps to get to the final constant are the same?

Comment: @IsaacBrenig Every time we calculate the difference of the sequence, we are somehow derivating the sequence. So the smount of steps to get the constant sequence is the same with that to get the constant function $y=6$. (In the case of example 1)